# keep getting null from OpenArgs parameter

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

In MS Access 2010 I've created a database with two forms.  I'm attempting to pass data from the first form to the second form.  The first form has a button on it which opens the second form, however it is supposed to pass on two parameters like so:

```
Private Sub Command14_Click()
Dim data As String
data = Me.Schedule_ID.Value & "|" & Me.Schedule_Name.Value
'MsgBox data
DoCmd.OpenForm "Set Employees, Dates And Times", acNormal, , , , , data
End Sub
```

On the second form, I'm trying to retrieve the OpenArg parameter like so:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
MsgBox Me.OpenArgs  '<<< OpenArgs is Null!
Dim Pstring As Variant
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
   Pstring = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
   Me.txtPlannedScheduleID.Value = Pstring(0)
   Me.txtPlannedScheduleName.Value = Pstring(1)
End If
End Sub
```

It stalls on the fist line MsgBox Me.OpenArgs.  OpenArgs is Null.  Why is that?  How do I fix it?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.